# EverlyWell - legit?

Tags: blood-tests, test, procedural-expectations, qualifiy-certify

EverlyWell is a lab testing startup. I'm looking at their [food sensitivity test](https://www.everlywell.com/products/food-sensitivity), didn't find a whole lot of independent info online (other than blogger reviews that were paid by the company).

Is it legit? Do they need to be certified to do such tests? Do they have the certifications? Any (independent) personal experience?